# Create React App: Set HTTPS flag in package.json based on .env variable

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, package.json

To enable create react app to run in SSL mode, we need to set HTTPS=true in the package.json like this

```
    "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
```

However, I would like this only in production and not when development happens locally. I have a .env file, and would like to use a flag `REACT_APP_USE_SSL=true` in production and then `REACT_APP_USE_SSL=false` locally.

My question is, how can I use this environment variable in package.json? Or is there another way to seamlessly switch between HTTP and HTTPS mode for development and production environment?

Comment: We can do that, check this section in docs https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used

Comment: Thank you @kiranvj, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @kiranvj, (and also after the reading the doc myself), this is easier than the other complicated solutions I was trying to implement.

You can just set `HTTPS=true` or `HTTPS=false` in your .env file and create react app will pick it up.